# How to export list into self-formatted text file in R?

Tags: r, text, dplyr

I have a list which looks like this:

```
name <- c("A","B","C","D","E")
n <- c("1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10", "11, 12, 13, 14, 15", "16, 17, 18, 19, 20", "21, 22, 23, 24, 25", "26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35")
type <- c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e")

list <- list(name=name,n=n,type=type)

$name
[1] "A" "B" "C" "D" "E"

$n
[1] "1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10"          "11, 12, 13, 14, 15"                     "16, 17, 18, 19, 20"                    
[4] "21, 22, 23, 24, 25"                     "26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35"

$type
[1] "a" "b" "c" "d" "e"
```

I need to export the list in a text file looks like this:

```
name = "A",
type = "a",
n = 1, 2, 3, 4, 5,
    6, 7, 8, 9, 10
name = "B",
type = "b",
n = 11, 12, 13, 14, 15
name = "C",
type = "c",
n = 16, 17, 18, 19, 20
name = "D",
type = "d",
n = 21, 22, 23, 24, 25
name = "E",
type = "e",
n = 26, 27, 28, 29, 30,
    31, 32, 33, 34, 35
```

This text file follows the following format:

- `name`, `n` and `type` are a group. It means that, i.e., `name="A", n=1,2,...10, type="a"` are one set of record.
- Each *element name* (`name`, `n` and `type`) is placed at the beginning of each row.
- Each *element contents* (i.e., `11, 12, 13, 14, 15` is a content of `n`) is placed after *element name*. Some *element contents*, in this case, data kept in `name` and `type` are surrounded by double quotation `"` but those in `n` are not surrounded by double quotation. This setting can be changed according to the needs.
- Each *element contents* is separated by comma `,` at the end of each *element contents*, such as `name = "A",`.
- It should be noted that *element contents* of `n` already contains comma as it is string type data. However, if `n` contains more than 5 numbers, column shall begin on the new line. (This data seems to be tricky. It may be better to convert `string` to `integer` first as the length of each number is not unified.)
- On the other hand, the last *element contents*, which means `type` in this example, does not have a comma at its end as a new set of `name`, `n` and `type` starts from the next row

I used to use R for more simple data manipulation but have never used it for this kind of text manipulation. Your suggestions are highly appreciated.

I prefer to use pipe function in `dplyr` but the solution is not limited to this package. Thank you in advance for your kind suggestions.

Comment: you're probably best off rolling your own function. strwrap will help a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This isn't a very straightforward string manipulation for R. The heart of string concatenation is `paste()` and `paste0()`. You can use `mapply()` to iterate over the elements in your list at the same time. Basically you just have to get everything to line up. For example

```
rows <- paste0(mapply(function(name,n,type) {
  n <- strsplit(n, ", ")[[1]]
  parts <- unlist(tapply(n, (seq_along(n)-1)%/%5, paste, collapse=", "))
  val <- paste0(paste(
    paste0("name = ", dQuote(name, q=FALSE)),
    paste0("type = ", dQuote(type, q=FALSE)),
    paste0(rep(c("n = ", "    "), c(1, length(parts)-1)), parts, collapse=",\n"),
    sep = ",\n"), "\n")
}, 
    list$name, list$n, list$type, SIMPLIFY=TRUE), collapse="")

cat(rows)
```

returns

```
name = "A",
type = "a",
n = 1, 2, 3, 4, 5,
    6, 7, 8, 9, 10
name = "B",
type = "b",
n = 11, 12, 13, 14, 15
name = "C",
type = "c",
n = 16, 17, 18, 19, 20
name = "D",
type = "d",
n = 21, 22, 23, 24, 25
name = "E",
type = "e",
n = 26, 27, 28, 29, 30,
    31, 32, 33, 34, 35
```

Be sure to use `cat()` to the newline characters are expanded in the output.